# error: expected primary-expression before '<' token : arduino RGB dancing lights

Tags: c++, arduino

This code doesn't work.

Tried googling it (am relatively new to C++)

This code is meant to change the power level on pins 3,4,5 based on the sound level picked up from the sound sensor on the breadboard. I've checked the sound levels with the serial monitor and it seems to have the right numbers on it so I think that the IF statement is wrong.

```
[code]
int DO = 2; //Pin for Digital Output - DO
int DA = A0; // Pin for Analog Output - AO
int threshold = 45; //Set minimum threshold for LED lit
int sensorvalue = 0;

void setup() {
//  Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
sensorvalue = analogRead(DA);  //Read the analog value
//  Serial.print("Analog: ");
//  Serial.print(sensorvalue);  //Print the analog value
//  Serial.print("  ");
//  Serial.print("Digital: ");
//  Serial.println(digitalRead(DO));  //Print the digital value

if (sensorvalue =< 40) {
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
}
if (sensorvalue =< 45) {
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
}
if (sensorvalue =< 50) {
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
}
else {
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
}
}

[/code]

Should leave no error.
Digital pins 3,4,5 should output the stated power level depending on the sound level from the sound sensor on the board.
```

Comment: As well as the `=<` to `<=` change, you might also want to change the second and third `if` to `else if` otherwise you going to setting setting the pins three times each. For instance if `sensorValue` is 40 then all three if statements are going to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a valid c++ [operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) `=<`

should be change to `<=`

Comment: wow im stupid thanks. I was using python statements......

Comment: @Ben711Gaming same can happen when I do python :). I check the syntax before writing anything in python